# jupyter kernel restarts during long-running executions on a jupyter notebook server in a docker container running a nginx/1.13.12 webserver

Tags: docker, nginx, jupyter

I'm running a jupyter notebook server in a docker container which is running a nginx webserver. In the `Dockerfile` I start the notebook in a bash script instead of starting it directly with `CMD`. The notebook server runs and is accessible at port 8888, I'm able to access it after the container is running and create new notebooks, run cells, etc. However, when I run a long-running cell after about 5-8 minutes of running the kernel restarts.

The long running job started at ~17:28:00. Here's the jupyter server's output:

```
[I 17:24:45.893 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[W 17:24:46.152 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using encryption. This is not recommended.
[W 17:24:46.153 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using authentication. This is highly insecure and not recommended.
[I 17:24:46.171 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /AI-Dev-Platform
[I 17:24:46.171 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 17:24:46.172 NotebookApp] http://(5b90bb002e97 or 127.0.0.1):8888/
[I 17:24:46.172 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 17:24:48.144 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/ea0b8015-ea5c-4f59-9bd8-dc107b210906/channels?session_id=313f5ba19f5f43c387da66fc8a51ec29 (172.17.0.1): Kernel does not exist: ea0b8015-ea5c-4f59-9bd8-dc107b210906
[W 17:24:48.179 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/ea0b8015-ea5c-4f59-9bd8-dc107b210906/channels?session_id=313f5ba19f5f43c387da66fc8a51ec29 (172.17.0.1) 43.93ms referer=None
[W 17:25:20.250 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: ea0b8015-ea5c-4f59-9bd8-dc107b210906:313f5ba19f5f43c387da66fc8a51ec29
[I 17:25:27.270 NotebookApp] Writing notebook-signing key to /root/.local/share/jupyter/notebook_secret
[W 17:25:27.272 NotebookApp] Notebook scratch.ipynb is not trusted
[I 17:25:28.016 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 54405c35-1ef0-4afc-a09c-e7cc78e4cd99
[I 17:25:28.769 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel 54405c35-1ef0-4afc-a09c-e7cc78e4cd99
[I 17:27:27.708 NotebookApp] Saving file at /scratch.ipynb
[I 17:33:28.044 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
WARNING:root:kernel 54405c35-1ef0-4afc-a09c-e7cc78e4cd99 restarted
```

The bash script that starts the notebook is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to be run by the Dockerfile CMD - starts a notebook

echo "Running a Jupyter notebook on port 8888. Redirecting Jupyter            output to jupyter.log"
echo -e "Jupyter notebook password is empty"
mkdir /root/.jupyter
echo -e "c.NotebookApp.token = u''
c.NotebookApp.password = u''
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888" > /root/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
jupyter notebook -y --allow-root --ip=* --no-browser --notebook-dir=/AI-Dev-Platform >& jupyter.log &
python main.py
echo -e "Jupyter notebook is running on port 8888, password is empty"
```

`nginx.conf`:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    # These two lines prevent timeouts
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 999999;

    # Jupyter server config
    server {
        listen 443;
        listen 8888 default_server;
        listen [::]:8888 default_server;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
        location ~* /(api/kernels/[^/]+/(channels|iopub|shell|stdin)|terminals/websocket)/? {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            # WebSocket support
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

        }
    }

}
daemon off;
```

Docker version:

`18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40`

jupyter versions:

```
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.2.3
jupyter-console==5.2.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
```